# Rollup + @babel/preset-env + @babel/polyfill

Tags: javascript, babeljs, rollup, babel-polyfill, babel-preset-env

When using Rollup how can you get it to work with both `@babel/preset-env` and `@babel/polyfill`? The docs mentioned to add `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` but when I do this I get a `require is not defined` error in console. Below is what I have so far; is there a more recommended setup?

rollup.config.js:

```js
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

const dist = './dist/';
const name = 'focusoverlay';

export default {
  input: './src/index.js',
  output: [
    {
      file: `${dist}${name}.cjs.js`,
      format: 'cjs'
    },
    {
      file: `${dist}${name}.esm.js`,
      format: 'esm'
    },
    {
      name: 'FocusOverlay',
      file: `${dist}${name}.js`,
      format: 'umd'
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
      resolve(),
      babel({ exclude: 'node_modules/**' }),
      terser()
  ]
};
```

.babelrc:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": "> 0.25%, not op_mini all, not dead, IE 10-11",
          "node": 6
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I fixed this by removing my `.babelrc` file and moving my babel configuration entirely to `rollup.config.js`. Then I also included the `rollup-plugin-commonjs` plugin to convert CJS modules to ES6. Example of my final config:

```js
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

const dist = './dist/';
const name = 'focusoverlay';

export default {
  input: './src/index.js',
  output: [
    {
      file: `${dist}${name}.cjs.js`,
      format: 'cjs'
    },
    {
      file: `${dist}${name}.esm.js`,
      format: 'esm'
    },
    {
      name: 'FocusOverlay',
      file: `${dist}${name}.js`,
      format: 'umd'
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
      resolve(),
      babel({
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
        presets: [
          [
            '@babel/env',
            {
              modules: 'false',
              targets: {
                browsers: '> 1%, IE 11, not op_mini all, not dead',
                node: 8
              },
              useBuiltIns: 'usage'
            }
          ]
        ]
      }),
      commonjs(),
      terser()
  ]
};
```

Full config [here](https://github.com/mmahandev/FocusOverlay/blob/master/rollup.config.js). Suggestions for improvement of course still welcome.

Comment: ```rollup-plugin-babel``` has been deprecated. https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel

Comment: @MdTahazzot no, the repository just moved.

Comment: @jbg Ops, right. Thanks for reminding me. Have a nice day.